# System boots directly in to Windows

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion dv6 notebook but I am trying to dual-boot with Windows for the last couple of days without any success. The installation CD is ejected after installing Ubuntu and Windows is loaded after that.

How can I dual-boot Ubuntu with Windows?

Comment: The CD could be corrupt. Have you tried re-downloading the ISO and burn it again? The disc drive could also have problems.

Comment: I think You have already installed Ubuntu but your system directly boots in to Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CD is mostly corrupted. Do you have VirtualBox or any other similar software to test the disc with? If not, install it and test the disc for DEFECTS.

**Procedure to check the disc for defects:**

1) Place the Ubuntu disc into the CD/DVD drive.
2) Wait for the Ubuntu boot screen and press ANY key (I use space though). It wil prompt you with keyboard layout option. By default, the keyboard layout is en-us (it is an international default unless you specifically purchased another variant).

3) Now, after that, you will see the "Check the media for defects" option with similar message.
4) Select it and sit back for a while. It will check the installation media to determine any defects.

The output from step 4 will give you a proper idea where the problem lies. If the outcomes positive, then make sure you have the [minimum system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) to install Ubuntu.